# MarkLogic manage/v3 API throwing error with POST call

Tags: rest, api, marklogic-9

I am using MarkLogic 9.0-9.1 version. I have two test databases:

1. database: test1  forest: test1-forest
2. database: test2  forest: test2-forest

I use the manage/v3 api get the database and forests configuration of my existing MarkLogic server. This gives me all the databases within my existing environment.

```
`curl -X GET --anyauth --user admin:admin "http://localhost:8002/manage/v3?format=xml&include-properties=true&resource-type=database,forest" > c:\config\dbconfig.xml`
```

Now for a different MarkLogic environment I want to use this configuration to create the databases and the forests, it throws error with the POST call.

```
`curl -v -X POST --anyauth --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/xml" -d@c:\Config\dbconfig.xml "http://localhost:8002/manage/v3"`
```

> Error: `<message>`CMA-INVALIDPROPERTIES (err:FOER0000): MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOADerr:FOER00001.0-mlPayload has errors in structure, content-type or values.MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD: (err:FOER0000) Payload has errors in structure, content-type or values. XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE: (err:XQDY0027) validate strict { fn:trace($database-properties, $trace-event) } --

I have validated the xml and it is well formed and UTF-8 encoded. Please suggest what needs to be done here to remove this error.

I have already tried to use just the two new database as part of the config, but I get the same error. The versions of the environments are same. The systems are running on Linux. The same error is encountered on MarkLogic installed in Windows too.

Edit: I have tried this with json as well, and the same error persists.

Comment: It might be worth reaching out to Support via your MarkLogic contact. They will be able to analyze your configuration in full detail, which might be needed to understand the exact issue.